# Listen to custom object - QuickBlox

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox

I've managed to add/edit/delete/update custom objects in the QuickBlox back-end.

However, I want the user to "listen" to a certain object, and if the value has changed I want to let the user know.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to "listen" for any changes on custom objects: there is property updatedAt, but you need to load custom object from server (by QBRequest) in order to get this field up to date from server.